# Embed link to most recent YouTube video

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube

I'm looking for a code that will embed a hyperlink to my most recent YouTube video. Something like what this does – https://latestyoutu.be/

I've used the below code in order to embed an iframe of the most recent video, but i'm struggling to convert it into a text hyperlink. I also need it to link to the actual page on YouTube, rather than an embedded iframe.

Thanks

```
<script id="youtubeLatest" style="color: red;">
(async function channelID (channelID) {
  const reqURL = "https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=" + encodeURIComponent("https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=") + channelID;
  const repl = await fetch(reqURL).then(r => r.json());
  const url = repl.items[0].link;
  document.write(`<a href="${url}" target="_blank">Latest Upload</a>`);
})("UCWzZ5TIGoZ6o-KtbGCyhnhg");
</script>
```

Comment: Here's code you can plug in a <script>: https://pastebin.com/T8PhaZPz ([codepen](https://codepen.io/khrismuc/pen/QWvmEXL))

Comment: @ChrisG thank you so much, this worked! Which tag do I use to style the text in CSS?

Comment: Give it `id="youtube_latest"` and you can use `#youtube_latest { ... }` or use an inline-style like `style="color: red;"`

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks! One more question. How would you go about automatically loading this script and going to the link upon page load? I've tried the onload tag with no sucess.

Comment: @ChrisG also the CSS style isn't working for some reason

Comment: @ChrisG I've added the updated code to the post. Any idea how I can fix the styling as well as add an onload function?

Comment: You don't need styling if you go to the youtube video though? Instead of the document.write call, do `location = url;`, that'll redirect to the video. (Also, you need to add the `id` / `style` to the `<a>`, not the script.)

Comment: @ChrisG you're a genius mate. thanks for helping out a noob. we don't need to style it, but if I did need to, how would i? putting inline style in the <a> didn't work. I even went back to your codepen and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: I updated the pen with an inline style. The id/CSS method doesn't work on codepen but should work with an inline script (on codepen, using document.write wrecks the DOM, which is why one usually shouldn't use it)